# Example of safety violation when cast char *argv[] to (const char * const *)

Tags: c++, c, constants

There's a well-known warning in gcc

```
warning: passing argument ... from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

and most often it occurs when trying to do something with parameter `argv` of function `main`.

I've read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28702525/447503 . Ok, the C standard says so and the following code will compile with a warning:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        const char * const * b = argv;
        return b == 0;
}
```

Not sure about C++, because g++ compiles same code without warnings.

Is there any reason behind this part of the standard? Can I do something bad after the cast, for example make `argv` point to non-writable memory?

This may be a duplicate of [Why can't I convert 'char**' to a 'const char* const*' in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125/why-cant-i-convert-char-to-a-const-char-const-in-c) , but Aaron's anwer is incorrect: read the comments.

Is Kevin's answer incorrect?

I'm thinking to add a convenience inline function like: `const char * const *foo(char * const *a)`. Unlike C-style casts it would be type safe.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Aaron's anwer is incorrect: read the comments.

Comment: I agree that the linked duplicate had some questionable answers, voting to re-open this in hope that someone can provide a better answer.

Comment: "Is Kevin's answer incorrect?" -- No, that answer is correct. The conversion can be safe (assuming the language's aliasing rule allows it too -- which C++'s does). If it weren't safe, C++ wouldn't have opened this up. @Lundin I think the question should've remained closed, Aaron's answer to that other question indeed misses the point, but the accepted answer there is correct.

Comment: The accepted answer in the duplicate is correct. Why ask it again? If you're looking for more details, such as exact quotes from the C and C++ standards, you should state so.

Comment: I don't believe there's a problem with the C standard, it is very clear. Rather seems GCC doesn't like the pointer to be promoted to qualified pointer-to-type, for reasons unknown. You can rule out all strangeness with constant pointers like this: `typedef const char const_char;   const_char** ptr = argv;` and you still get that warning.

Comment: C11: `For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal.` And that text is all there is, how could it be misinterpreted? How can there be "a problem with the standard"?

Comment: It could, because it's human language. If standards were example-driven, there would be much less misunderstanding

Comment: From the C++ side  I think my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29240053/1708801) is what you are looking for. The logic should be similar for C.

Comment: @Lundin Nobody said anything about misinterpreting. The problem is that the C standard doesn't allow some code which is actually safe, such as that in the question.