# Why does C in contrast to C++ ban adding const-qualification to both levels of a pointer-to-pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants, pointer-to-pointer

I have the following situation:

A function creates an array of strings and then passes this to a bunch of other functions. These other functions should not modify neither pointers pointed to by the outer pointer nor the strings themselves, so I made them const.

Minimal example:

```
void function(const char * const *arr) {
    /* Do something useful */
}

int main(void) {
    char **x;
    /* fill x and *x */
    function(x);
}
```

When compiling with gcc or clang this gives me a warning, that x is converted to an incompatible pointer type.

While I understand why the pointer type is incompatible if I remove the second const in the parameter list of function (explained here: [Why does passing char** as const char** generate a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning)), I do not understand why it is incompatible with the const.

Compiling with a c++-Compiler does not give me the warning (See comparison here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YND5U7)

Comment: You should mention the command line arguments used for compiling. However, I fiddled a bit in godbolt with your sample: [**Comparison in godbolt**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YND5U7). I can confirm your observation. (You may use it in your question if you like.) It looks like whether C does type-check stricter than C++ in this case. (Usually, it's vice versa, isn't it?) :-)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701376/incompatible-pointer-types-and-constness

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180809/gcc-issues-warning-of-incompatible-pointer-type

Comment: Actually it's not a duplicate. The referenced question asks for `char**` -> `const char **`. I asked for `char**` -> `const char * const *`

Comment: @urzeit Hmm, ok - I removed the dup but I still think the answer is the same as the provided links

Comment: @4386427: I don't think so. The reason why `char **` -> `const char **` is dangerous does not apply with the second const, since the pointed to pointer cannot be modified.

Comment: Would you mind adding the actual warning you got?

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand why it is incompatible with the `const`.

Note: `const1, const2` defined for clarity to distinguish the two.

In C, the `const2` in `const1 char * const2 *arr` is the qualifier `x` optionally matches.  `const2` say that `function(const1 char * const2 *arr)` has a contract with the calling code, it will not change what `arr` points to.  `arr` points to a `const1 char *`.  `arr` can be `const1 char **` or `const1 char * const2 *`.

In `main()`, incompatible because `*x` points to a `char *` and not a `const1 char *`.  What it points to is different than what `function()` expects.  `const1` is not part of the `function()` no-write contract.  Instead, `const1 char *` is a type and that differs from `char *`.

At this point, I see no reason why C could not have been specified differently to allowed a `char *` to be treated like a `const1 char *` in `function()` - it is simply a case that C does not allow it.

```
#define const1 const
#define const2 const
void function(const1 char * const2 *arr) {
    // Do something useful
}

int main(void) {
    char **x = 0;
    function(x);  // bad  
    // note: expected 'const char * const*' but argument is of type 'char **'

    const char **x2 = 0;
    function(x2); // OK
}
```

---

No comment on C++

Comment: So this is a language restriction to make life easier for compiler implementers?

Comment: Well, C++ specified it later, and took the time to make sure it was right. C could have adopted it in the next standard...

Comment: @Deduplicator Do you know if this was resolved in [C18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C18_(C_standard_revision))?  (I'll review [it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf) too)

Comment: It doesn't look like there's any change in that area, unfortunately.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah. It's a bug in the spec.